# Can I read Bhagavata Purana? If yes, what are the procedures and rules to be followed?

Tags: bhagavata-purana

I wanted to know if I can read Srimad Bhagavatam on a daily basis at home. Either in morning or in evening. If yes, what are the procedures to be followed while reading?

Comment: Hello Presanna. Welcome to [hinduism.se]. We are a bit different from other Hinduism forums. Take a [tour] of our site and check [ask] to know more about our site. Have a nice experience here.

Comment: You can read Bhagavatam as much as you like. There are no restrictions or rules to be followed.

Comment: once started, complete it in 18days,its written in it. Else you wont remember the beginning if you reach its end after 6months